# Magento redirect to product page after add to wishlist for user who is not logged in

Tags: magento, redirect

Scenario:
When user is not logged in

What i want:
- When User click on wishlist 
- Magento Redirect to Login Page
- After Successful login user need to redirect to recently used page i.e product page

What is happening:
- User redirected to dashboard after login

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear.
But try this if you are searching for it.
You can change the setting in admin

System->Configuration->Customer->Customer Configuration->Login option
Change the setting Redirect Customer to Account Dashboard after Logging in to No.

There are also free extension available.
Thanks,

Answer (score -1):

Your Question is clear and here is your Answer.

You can override the add to wishlist action in the wishlist controller and make it redirect to the referrer.

Override this method Mage_Wishlist_IndexController::addAction() and replace this:

$this->_redirect('*', array('wishlist_id' => $wishlist->getId()));

with this:

$this->_redirectReferer()

Comment: This will not work as the referrer will be the account login page and it will redirect to account page after adding product to wishlist.

Comment: You need to provide a full solution. There are no details at all with the latter code.